# VS2017 Project configuration preprocessor definitions not working in C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I have a preprocessor definition called PRIVATE_CODE set in my VS2017 project properties (VS2017 version 15.9.6 on Windows 8.1):

- Right-click on solution
- Configuration Properties
- C/C++
- Preprocessor
- Preprocessor Definitons (field)

However, when I look at code in any file that looks for it to be defined, the code is not in use.  I can tell because in my dark themed IDE, the code is in the IFDEF section is dimmed and the code in the ELSE section is normal brightness.

To be absolutely sure, I put a bad line of code in each section to see which section triggered a compiler error:

```
#ifdef PRIVATE_CODE
    // This should trigger a compiler error.
    adadfadsf;
#else
   // Instead, I get a compiler error here, indicating that the compiler
   //  is not paying attention to the preprocessor definitions I set.
   asdfadfff;
#endf
```

Has anybody else had this problem and knows why this is happening?

Comment: Are you modifying the properties for the same configuration as what you're compiling? Make sure the combination of "Configuration" and "Platform" at the top of the Properties window match what you're building. That's bit me many times.

Comment: ^ especially if you're using a command-line build process instead of doing it in the IDE.  The other obvious thing to check is for a mismatch typo in the #ifdef vs. project settings.  Edit the preprocessor settings and copy the PRIVATE_CODE entry then paste it into your CPP file just to make sure.